# npm test failing without any error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm

The tests are failing with no errors and just with above message.

My test script is:

```
"test": "TEST=true tape test/core/*.js test/core/ui/user-interface.js test/core/modules/QR.js | tap-spec; browserify test/core/modules/image-sequencer.js test/core/modules/chain.js test/core/modules/meta-modules.js test/core/modules/replace.js test/core/modules/import-export.js test/core/modules/run.js test/core/modules/dynamic-imports.js test/core/util/parse-input.js test/core/modules/benchmark.js| tape-run --render="tap-spec"",
```

Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1
- node: 10.15.3
- npm: 6.4.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it more easy to understand. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Are you getting a result in console prior to the pipe into tap-spec?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if you have any threshold configured in your project.

According to jest documentation, https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration, if you set a "coverageThreshold" on your jest.config.js the test will fail if there is less than 80% branch, line, and function coverage, according to the configuration bellow.

```
"coverageThreshold": {
  "global": {
    "branches": 80,
    "functions": 80,
    "lines": 80,
    "statements": -10
  }
}
```

You can pass all tests but jest will fail if you do not accomplish the threshold specified. Moreover, it does not give you any tips about this on the error log.

I had the same issue with an angular project and it was due to this configuration.